# Derivative of a product of a matrix and a vector with respect to a parameter

Tags: derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let say that $A \in R^{n,m}$ and $x \in R^{m,1}$, the elements of $A$ and $x$ are differentiable functions of $\theta$.

What is the derivative of the product $Ax$ with respect to the parameter $\theta$ :

$$\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial \theta}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's denote the Matrix $A = \begin{pmatrix} g_{1,1}(\theta) & g_{1,2}(\theta), ...\\ g_{2,1}(\theta) & g_{2,2}(\theta), ...\\.\\.\\.\end{pmatrix}$.

Then it holds $Ax = \begin{pmatrix}g_{1,1}(\theta)\cdot x_1(\theta) + g_{1,2}(\theta)\cdot x_2(\theta) + ...\\
g_{2,1}(\theta)\cdot x_1(\theta) + g_{2,2}(\theta)\cdot x_2(\theta) + ...\\.\\.\\.\end{pmatrix}$.

You can easily differentiate every summand of every entry of the vector, w.r.t to $\theta$ by product rule, to get (I dropped "$(\theta)$" here for simple notation)
$$
\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial \theta} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
(g'_{1,1} \cdot x_1+ g_{1,1} \cdot x_1')+ (g'_{1,2}\cdot x_2 + g_{1,2} \cdot x_2')+ ...\\
(g'_{2,1} \cdot x_1+ g_{2,1} \cdot x_1')+ (g'_{2,2}\cdot x_2 + g_{2,2} \cdot x_2')+ ...\\
.\\.\\.
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Laray, the entries of $x$ are also depend on $\theta$, I guess you did not notice that.

Comment: Yep, was an oversight on that, be right back with results...

Comment: user137684 And here they are!

Comment: So from your response, we can write $\frac {\partial Ax}{\partial \theta} = \frac {\partial A}{\partial \theta}x+A \frac {\partial x}{\partial \theta}$.

Comment: I did not realise this, but yes, you are right. Seems like product rule works in matric-calculus as well...